# C# LINQ get records from datatable group by hour

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable whose columns are name, code, dateAndTime. Now I want to get the count of all the records for every hour in a Day using LINQ.

DateTime Column contains data as

```
2014-08-01 07:00:06.163
2014-08-01 07:00:11.873
2014-08-01 07:00:42.623
2014-08-01 07:00:48.363
2014-08-01 07:01:15.243
2014-08-01 07:01:16.507
```

Now I want to get the count of all the records from the start of the day to the end of the day hourly basis.

Example would be :

```
7 O Clock : 56 Records
8 O Clock : 90 Records
..
..
etc.
```

How it can be possible via LINQ ?

Comment: Yes possible. But what you have tried? Which part you don't know/ not working?

Comment: If two records are on different days but in the same hour, do you want to sum them or count separately?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your column type is `DateTime` then you can group by its `Hour` property and get count for each hour like:

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<DateTime>("dateAndTime").Hour)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Hour = grp.Key,
        Count = grp.Count()
    });
```

where `dt` is your `DataTable`

EDIT: The above should work as long as you have data for a single date in your `DataTable`, but if you have rows for multiple dates then grouping should be done on `Date` as well as `Hour` like:

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new
    {
        Date = row.Field<DateTime>("dateAndTime").Date, 
        Hour = row.Field<DateTime>("dateAndTime").Hour
    })
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Date = grp.Key.Date,
        Hour = grp.Key.Hour,
        Count = grp.Count()
    });
```

Comment: This would group days together. You should also group by dateTime.Date. The question is not well written but I think this line describes this requirement "from the start of the day to the end of the day"

Comment: @Pluc, you are right I should modify that, from the Data, it looks like there is date for a single day.

Comment: My day starts from 7 O clock. So, it should be 7 to 7. Later 7 will fall to next date.

Comment: isn't "asEnumerable" going to extract all data from db and then use linq queries on the list to group it? If so you should do it at the end.

Comment: The LINQ query is on DataTable, it already has the data in Memory.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the column really stores `DateTime`s, you can group by `Date` + `Hour`:

```
 var hourGroups = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new { DateAndTime = row.Field<DateTime>("dateAndTime"), Row = row })
    .GroupBy(x => new { Date = x.DateAndTime.Date, Hour = x.DateAndTime.Date.Hour });

foreach (var x in hourGroups)
    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0} Hour: {1}: Count: {2} All names: {3}", 
        x.Key.Date.ToShortDateString(),
        x.Key.Hour,
        x.Count(),
        string.Join(",", x.Select(xx => xx.Row.Field<string>("name")))); // just bonus
```